# Multiplying and adding big numbers represented with strings

Tags: javascript, integer

I got a very unusual problem of adding and multiplying very big numbers (≥ 1e+100). So I've written simple functions that would operate on string representations of numbers, both as an input and an output.

Multiplication:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
    if ((a | 0) == 0 || (b | 0) == 0) {
        return '0';
    }

    a = a.split('').reverse();
    b = b.split('').reverse();
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; a[i] >= 0; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; b[j] >= 0; j++) {
            if (!result[i + j]) {
                result[i + j] = 0;
            }

            result[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; result[i] >= 0; i++) {
        if (result[i] >= 10) {
            if (!result[i + 1]) {
                result[i + 1] = 0;
            }

            result[i + 1] += parseInt(result[i] / 10);
            result[i] %= 10;
        }
    }

    return result.reverse().join('');
}
```

Addition:

```
function add(a, b) {
    if ((a | 0) == 0 && (b | 0) == 0) {
        return '0';
    }

    a = a.split('').reverse();
    b = b.split('').reverse();
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; (a[i] >= 0) || (b[i] >= 0); i++) {
        var sum = (parseInt(a[i]) || 0) + (parseInt(b[i]) || 0);

        if (!result[i]) {
            result[i] = 0;
        }

        var next = ((result[i] + sum) / 10) | 0;
        result[i] = (result[i] + sum) % 10;

        if (next) {
            result[i + 1] = next;
        }
    }

    return result.reverse().join('');
}
```

Are there better ways of doing this job? Some additional edge cases or better loop conditions, maybe?

Comment: Unless this is just for fun you'd be better off looking for a bignum library instead.

Comment: Take a look at [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum); I'm quite fond of it. (I'd review your code if I did enough Javascript to understand half of it)

Comment: Your function works for small numbers but for large numbers, it is not working. e.g. multiply('1111','222222222222222222222222222222') resulted in 0. Fix it please.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the correct functions to convert to types

I think you are using the bitwise `|` to convert a string to a number:

```
if ((a | 0) == 0 || (b | 0) == 0) {
    return '0';
}
```

I think `parseInt` can show this intent more clearly:

```
if (parseInt(a) == 0 || parseInt(b) == 0) {
    return '0';
}
```

Comment: That would get you an Integer not any number (floating point). Not a big difference, but it would be helpful to point it out as you wouldn't use it just anywhere